# School Boundary

Tags: geospatial, data.gov, data-mapping

I need to find **individual** school boundaries (primary for the State of California). 
There are maybe 2 or 3 similar questions to this one (here and GIS exchange), but no answer down to the single school.

We can find the *district* boundary, and that is helpful. But not individual schools inside that broad district boundary.

We can also find the boundaries of each physical school location (as opposed as to attendance boundary).

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

---

Update images from files downloaded from The National Center for Education Statistics' Education and Geographic Estimates.

[image]

And what they call elementary:
[image]

That [site](https://nces.ed.gov/), to the best of my knowledge, does not go down to individual schools.

Comment: Sorry, what are you asking? First you write *I need to find individual school boundaries*, then you write *We can also find the boundaries of each physical school location*.

Comment: Yes, you have attendance boundaries and school boundary. The first is the whole neighborhood that attends one school. The second is the physical area of the school. The second is available nationwide. The first... not so much.

Answer (score 1):

The National Center for Education Statistics' Education and Geographic Estimates [EDGE products](https://nces.ed.gov/programs/edge/Geographic/SchoolLocations) have geographic locations for public, private, and postsecondary schools in point geometry (.shp format). This might be useful, though you've asked about boundaries...

Comment: what I got from that site was district boundaries and what they call elementary (but it is not the same as elementary school boundaries). I uploaded images to the main question. That site provides district boundaries, which is very useful. But I need to go further. // And for some reason, it is no complete. They differentiate the school by places where a child that can go to more than one school and only one school. They prioritize the latter, as far as I can understand it.